# `If` `then` `else` not working in case of list in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

[Json Schema and Json](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/o9DI7CwQ)
I am trying to put a required check on certain variables based on what value is present in another attribute.
If `paymentType= Shopping_cards` then mandate `paymentRef1` and
if it is not then mandate other attributes. But when `paymentType != Shopping_cards` then also I am getting error for `paymentRef1`.
Not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Can somebody please help me out?
Both JSON schema and the request are present in the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` is inside `properties > payment > properties > paymentMethods > items`, so why not specify the condition relative to `items`. Change:

```
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "paymentMethods": {
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "paymentType": {
            "const": "SHOPPING_CARDS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

to:

```
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "paymentType": {
      "const": "SHOPPING_CARDS"
    }
  }
},
```

It works. I have no idea why the condition is true in the original version though.